# Two different Web IDEs on HANA Cloud Platform

Tags: sapui5, web-ide, sap-cloud-platform

I was following the blog post [SAP Web IDE - Enablement](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-55465) and noticed that I have been using a different Web IDE on HCP(HANA Cloud Platform). Can someone explain the two different Web IDEs.

**One is accessed via tha HANA Instances page as seen below:**
[image: ide_entry_point.png]
**and as you can see this is an old version and looks significantly different:**
[image: old_ide.png]
**and there is the other one (accessed via subscriptions menu) which is the up-to-date version and has many other capabilities:**
[image: ide.png]
[image: ide2.png]

So are these two IDEs different in terms of purpose?
As far as I understand, the second IDE(the new one) is used for local development and the application developed there can be deployed to HANA later on (the first one does not have any options related to deployment but it provides direct development on HANA) . Also there are other things that confuses me:

Can the second IDE connect to a HANA instance directly? We have xsjslib files that connects to the HANA DB and fetches data. ..or is the second editor is only for developing HTML5 applications without HANA connection?

Also in the this document it states that "If an HTML5 application requires connectivity to one or more back-end systems, destinations must be created or assigned". Can someone elaborate on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer with a parallel post on SCN Network: http://scn.sap.com/message/16139215

The bottom line is that(quoting the answer from the link)

> These are 2 different things, Web IDE and HANA Web Dev Workbench:
>   first is for SAPUI5/Fiori development/extension, second - HANA related
>   development.

So WebIDE is suitable for UI5 development meanwhile HANA Dev Workbench is for developing backend services.